# Fitting 2D functions in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I have two variables, x and y taking values in x_values and y_values :

```
x_values = np.linspace(x_min,x_max,n)
y_values = np.linspace(y_min,y_max,n)
```

And a measured 2D array z (n x n Matrix).

I'd like to fit z with a function, like in scipy.optimize.curve_fit.
But if I'm correct, this is only working for 1D functions.

My dream would be something like :

```
curve_fit2D(custom_2D_function, (x_values,y_values), z)
```

I couldn't find anything in scipy documentation, is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `curve_fit` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

```
xdata: array_like or object

    The independent variable where the data is measured. Should usually be an 
    M-length sequence or an (k,M)-shaped array for functions with k predictors, 
    but can actually be any object.
```

This means each column of your `xdata` must correspond to one entry of `z`.

## Solution

Reshape your data so you have one `(x, y)` pair for each `z`. Assuming `(x[i], y[j])` goes with `z[i, j]`, you can reshape this way.

```py
z_vec = z.flatten()
x_data = np.array([
    (x[i // z.shape[1]], y[i % z.shape[1]]) 
    for i in range(len(z_vec))
]).T

assert x_data.shape[1] == len(z_vec)
assert x_data.shape[0] == 2
```

Then use `curve_fit` as usual.

```py
curve_fit(custom_2D_function, x_data, z_vec)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, xdata must have the same shape as z. I'll work on a trick, but I'm sure something clean can be done

Comment: @hulyce it works for me. Are you sure that `z` is a 1D array of the same length as `x_values` and `y_values` (aka `(z.ndim == 1) and (len(z) == xdata.shape[1])`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @hulyce! You'll have to reshape your inputs to have one column of `xdata` for each entry in `z`. I've updated my answer to show how to do this.